# ListView isScrollCompleted() issue

Tags: android, android-listview, footer, android-adapter

I've a ListView with a custom adapter where i load information. I'm loading all the data retrived from a DB into an ArrayList (all the data is there) and i'm copying the data that i need as i scroll down into another ArrayList in order to show it:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products); 
    footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null, false);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    private void isScrollCompleted() {
    if (lv.getHeight() == footerView.getBottom(){
        update();
    }
public void update(){
    cargando=true;
    lv.removeFooterView(footerView);        
    eventos=generarClaseEventos(null, eventosFULL,eventos);
    adapter = new MyClassAdapter(AllProductsActivity.this,R.id.lista,eventos);              
    Comparator<Evento> comparador = new Comparator<Evento>() {
        @Override //metodo que compara fechas
        public int compare(Evento e1, Evento e2) {
            if (e1 == null) return 1;
            return e1.getFecha().compareTo(e2.getFecha());
        }
       };                   
       int index= lv.getFirstVisiblePosition(); //almaceno el indice y la posición
       View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
       int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();                 
       adapter.sort(comparador);//llamo al metodo sort que ordena
       lv.addFooterView(footerView);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                  
       lv.setSelectionFromTop(index, top); //restauro la posicion      
       cargando=false;          
}
```

The problem that i'm getting is that when i get to the bottom of my listview, i get my data loaded all the time until the app crashes. I'm getting the list view bottom and the footerview int's and they are the same all the time, like if i were scrolling down all the time but i'm not.
Why is this happening? I'm notifying my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
public void update(){
cargando=true;
lv.removeFooterView(footerView);        
eventos=generarClaseEventos(null, eventosFULL,eventos);
adapter = new MyClassAdapter(AllProductsActivity.this,R.id.lista,eventos);              
Comparator<Evento> comparador = new Comparator<Evento>() {
    @Override //metodo que compara fechas
    public int compare(Evento e1, Evento e2) {
        if (e1 == null) return 1;
        return e1.getFecha().compareTo(e2.getFecha());
    }
   };                   
   int index= lv.getFirstVisiblePosition(); //almaceno el indice y la posición
   View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
   int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();       
   footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null, false);          
   adapter.sort(comparador);//llamo al metodo sort que ordena
   lv.addFooterView(footerView);
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                  
   lv.setSelectionFromTop(index, top); //restauro la posicion      
   cargando=false;
```

}